# Enviar mensajes de feedback no funciona con redirección en Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

En aplicación Laravel 7.28.3, cuando redirecciono a una ruta **no se muestran los mensajes de feedback**.

*Los métodos en cuestión se llaman con una petición de tipo PUT.*

Esto funciona:

```
public function deactivate(int $id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->is_active = 0;
    $post->save();


    $posts = $this->getPosts();

    return view($this->view . '.index', compact($posts))
        ->with('success', 'Entrada desactivada');
}
```

Los siguientes ejemplos NO funcionan:

```
public function deactivate(int $id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->is_active = 0;
    $post->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Entrada desactivada');
}

public function deactivate(int $id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->is_active = 0;
    $post->save();

    return redirect()->route('posts')->with('success', 'Entrada desactivada');
}

public function deactivate(int $id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->is_active = 0;
    $post->save();

    session()->push('success', '1');
    session()->put('success', '2');
    session()->flash('success', '3');
    session()->reflash('success', '4');
    return redirect('private/posts')->with('success', 'Entrada desactivada');
}
```

> *Editado*

El mensaje de sesión se pierde en la redirección. Esta lleva al método `index()` del mismo controlador que devuelve la vista principal:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();

    return view('private.posts.index', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

Este método si devuelve 'feedbacks' y de hecho, al redireccionar, hasta el si llega el mensaje en sesión. Así, si cambio el método:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();

    return view('private.posts.index', ['posts' => $posts])
        ->with('success', session()->get('success'));
}
```

Recupero el feedback de la sesión y lo vuelvo a meter, entonces sí llegan y se muestran en la vista. Entonces, en este punto se esta limpiando la sesión.
*Por este mótivo probé, por ejemplo, `session()->reflash('success', '4');` que por lo que entendí en la documentación de Laravel podía haber funcionado...*

Comment: Cómo intentas obtener la variable success en el blade?

Comment: Tengo unos templates para los feedbacks, los uso en otras aplicaciones y como he dicho funcionan si el feedback se retorno con la vista, falla el redirect, no debería.. No estoy haciendo nada superextraño.

Answer (score 0):

Controlador:

```
public function returnWithSession(){
   return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'La categoría ha sido actualizada']);
}
```

Obtener la variable de sesión en blade:

```
@if(session()->has('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success col-md-4">{{ session()->get('success') }}</div>
@endif
```

[Visita este enlace para más información](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#using-the-session)

Comment: Esta forma de pasar el mensaje en un array, me la había dejado por probar, pero tampoco funciona. Voy a editar la pregunta para añadir otra prueba que hice.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con

Controlador:

```
\Session::flash('message','Permission has been added');
```

Vista:

```
@if(\Session::has('message'))
    {{session()->get('message')}}
@endif
```

Comment: Es lo mismo que `session()->flash('success', '3');`

Answer (score 0):

Vale cometí un error copiando y pegando...

Hay varias formas de pasar un mensaje de feedback "flaseado" a las vistas. En la pregunta las probé todas o casi, y funcionaban realmente, pero no tuve en cuenta "formas alternativas" de enviar datos a la vista...

Hay varias formas de enviar datos con el método `view()` que se confunde con una forma de *flasear* un mensaje al usar `redirect()`...

Ejemplo.

Imaginemos que voy a devolver un listado de *entradas* en el método `PostsController / index()`, tengo algo como:

```
public function index() 

{ 

    dump('PostsController / index()'); // HACK: trace 



    $posts = Post::all(); 





    return view('private.posts.index', ['posts => $posts]); 

}
```

Es lo que hago habitualmente.

En la vista para *pintar* las entradas:

```
@foreach($posts as $post) 



    ... 

@endforeach
```

Volviendo a la línea:

```
return view('private.posts.index', ['posts => $posts]);
```

puedo cambiarla por está y el resto seguirá funcionando igual:

```
return view('private.posts.index') 

    ->with('posts', $posts);
```

*El punto importante: el uso de `->with()`.*

#### Uso de `->with()` con `view()`

Estaba tratando de poner mensajes de feedback con esta sintaxis. Entonces en la vista recibía una variable, no un mensaje en la sesión. Así se puede:

```
return view('private.posts.index', ['posts => $posts]) 

    ->with('success', 'Recuperadas todas las entradas.');
```

Y en la vista tengo dos variables: `$posts` y `$success`, pero no tengo un mensaje de feedback en sesión y esto no imprime nada:

```
@if (session()->has('success')) 

    {{ session('success') }} 

@endif
```

La forma "correcta" sería está. Sin embargo, la traza aquí está en `$success`. Podía enviar mensajes con `view()` porque estaba imprimiendo con templates de feedback que copie de otro proyecto y funcionan con las variables. Así, esto también funcionaba (después de una redirección):

```
public function index() 

{ 

    $posts = Post::all(); 



    return view('private.posts.index', ['posts' => $posts]) 

        ->with('success', session()->get('success')); 

}
```

#### Uso de `->with()` con `redirect()`

En el redirect un mensaje se mete en la sesión entre otros métodos, encadenando `->with()`, por ejemplo:

```
return redirect()->back() 

    ->with('success', 'Entrada actualizada.');
```

Y esto no funciona si tratas de imprimir `$success`. De hecho, da un error si no tienes la estructura:

```
@if (isset($success)) 



    {{ $success }} 

@endif
```

#### Solución final

Como he mencionado lo más *correcto* sería usar en la vista:

```
@if (session()->has('success')) 

    {{ session('success') }} 

@endif 



Entonces a la hora de redireccionar: 



return redirect()->back() 

    ->with('success', 'Entrada actualizada.'); 



Y al usar `view()` podemos poner un mensaje en sesión de la siguiente forma: 



public function index() 

{ 

    dump('PostsController / index()'); // HACK: trace 



    $posts = Post::all(); 

    session()->flash('success', 'Listando entradas.'); 



    return view('private.posts.index', ['posts => $posts]); 

}
```