# Mi Laravel esta haciendo cosas raras... anomalía en seeders

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

En aplicación Laravel 7.28.3, en Ubuntu 18.04 / PHP 7.4.10

Ayer tenía este problema, al [usar re-direcciones se eliminan los mensajes de sesión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394253/enviar-mensajes-de-feedback-no-funciona-con-redirecci%C3%B3n-en-laravel-7), aun sin resolver...

Hoy me encuentro otro problema con los *seeders*. Esta es mi clase `DatabaseSeeder` funcionando:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Shop\CategoriesTableSeeder;
use Shop\ItemsTableSeeder;
use Shop\ProductsTableSeeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(MuPagesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(MuPostsTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(MuPostImagesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(CategoriesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call('ItemsTableSeeder');    
        $this->call('ProductsTableSeeder'); 
    }
}
```

La llamada a los dos últimos *seeders* es diferente...

No había forma de que reconociera las dos últimas clases si las llamaba con la "sintaxis" de las anteriores. Esto ocurre con independencia de que las ponga o no en un subdirectorio, con su correspondiente namespace...

Error:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
>
> Target class [Shop\ItemsTableSeeder] does not exist.
>
> at
> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:811

*Nota: limpie cache y regenere el autoload de clases al aparecer los errores, sin obtener un resultado diferente.*

Empiezo a sospechar de la versión de PHP, ya que con Laravel 8, hace unos días necesitabas la versión PHP 7.3 y ninguna otra...

**¿Alguna idea?**

Comment: Vale resuelto. Se me olvido poner el namespace dentro de las clases `ItemsTableSeeder` y `ProductsTableSeeder`.

Answer (score 0):

*En Laravel 7.28.3.*

Cuando se usa esta sintaxis en los *seeders*;

```
public function run()
{
    $this->call(ProductsTableSeeder::class);
}
```

El namespace tiene que ser correcto. Es decir, si el fichero con la clase `ProductsTableSeeder` se encuentra en el mismo directorio que `DatabaseSeeder.php` después de regenerar el *autoload* debe cargar sin problema.
Si se usan subdirectorios, las clases deben tener un namespace correctamente declarado. Es decir, que si `ProductsTableSeeder` se pone en el subdirectorio "Shop", llevara en la cabecera el *namespace*:

```
namespace Shop;
```

Y En la clase `DatabaseSeeder` su correspondiente clausula `use`:

```
use Shop\ProductsTableSeeder;
```

Podemos usar subdirectorios para almacenar los seeders y se ejecutarán correctamente con la sintaxis:

```
public function run()
{
    $this->call('ProductsTableSeeder');
}
```

En este caso no hay que poner *namespace* ni clausula `use`, el *autoload* registra los subdirectorios del directorio de "seeds",
aunque es una mala práctica usar clases sin namespaces en PHP desde hace años...

***Nota:** Laravel 8 ya incorpora [namespaces en los seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding#writing-seeders).*